# Why do I have to authorise HTC Sense to access Facebook?

Tags: htc-sense

Why do I have to authorise HTC Sense to access Facebook when I do not use Facebook on my phone and have no desire to do so?

Answer (score 0):

These days social media is built into many OS's. You can't disable some features such as integration with Facebook in this instance.